# Maximizing quadratic form subject to quadratic constraint

Tags: optimization, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, maxima-minima, quadratic-forms, qcqp

How can I  find the maximum and minimum value of the following quadratic form

$$Q(x) = x_1^2+3x_2^2+10x_1x_3+25x_3^2$$

subject to the equality constraint $\|x\|_2 = 3$? The norm is the Euclidian one.

---

Normally if I was given the constraint $\|x\|_2 = 1$ I would find the matrix A:

$$
A = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 5\\
0 & 3 & 0\\
5 & 0 & 25
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Where I would calculate the eigenvalues of $A$ , which are $\lambda_1 = 26, \lambda_2 = 3, \lambda_3 = 0.$ Then the maximum value  would be 26, and and the minimum value would be 0. But how am  I supposed to do this with a constraint such as $\|x\|_2 = 3$ ?

Any guidance will be much appreciated.

Comment: Hint: If $x^TAx=y$, then what is the value of $(3x)^TA(3x)$?

Comment: By that I can make it $9(x^TAx)$? And multiplying the largest eigenvalue with $9$ would give me $234$  which would be the largest value with the given constraint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem is homogeneous then calling $x_2 = \lambda x_1, x_3 = \mu x_1$ we arrive at

$$
\min(\max) \left(x_1^2\left(1+2\lambda^2+10\mu+25\mu^2\right)\right), \  \  \ \text{s. t.}\ \ \ x_1^2(1+\lambda^2+\mu^2)=k^2
$$

so we can follow without the constraint as

$$
\min(\max)_{\lambda,\mu} \frac{\left(1+2\lambda^2+10\mu+25\mu^2\right)k^2}{1+\lambda^2+\mu^2}
$$

and deriving we find the conditions

$$
\cases{
2 \lambda (10 \mu + 23 \mu^2-1) k^2=0\\
2 ( 5 \mu^2-5 - 5 \lambda^2 - 24 \mu - 23 \lambda^2 \mu) k^2=0
}
$$

giving the real solutions  $(\lambda=0,\mu = -\frac 15)$ and $(\lambda=0,\mu = 5)$ with respective minimum and maximum $(0, 26k^2)$

Answer (score 2):

If the norm of $\mathbf x=(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ is $3$, then the norm of $\frac13\mathbf x$ is $1$. Thus, if we multiply $Q(x)$ by $\frac19$ to get $R(x)$, the maximum and minimum of $R(x)$ with $\|\mathbf x\|=1$ translates to a maximum and minimum of $Q(x)$ with $\|\mathbf x\|=3$, by multiplying the solution vector for $R(x)$ by $3$ (and hence the extrema by $9$).

Comment: I am sorry, I find this concept difficult to grasp thus I may be asking some stupid questions. User amd commented that I should consider $(3x)^TA(3x)$ and from what I gathered this would give me the maximum value of 234, and the minimum value of 0. However by your method (if I understand it correctly) I am supposed to multiply the largest eigenvalues with $\sqrt{3}$? Which would give me the largest value of $45$?

Comment: Would this mean that I can calculate it as $3x^TAx$ and consider the solution for the constraint $x^TAx= 1$ which would give me that the largest eigenvalue is 26, and then I can multiply $26$ by $3$ which would give me the largest value with my constraint?

Comment: @ParclyTaxel in your answer you say that I should multiply the solution for R(x) by 3, shouldn't it be 9?

Comment: @dondeman Did you remember $(3x)^TA(3x)$?

Comment: Can I not write $(3x)^T A(3x)$ as $9(x^TAx)$  which would mean that I should multiply the solution with 9?

Comment: @dondeman If you multiplied the solution by $9$, you would have a vector of norm $9$, not $3$.

Comment: @amd Done. ${}$

Comment: Incidentally, calling $x^2+y^2+z^2$ a norm is a misnomer. One of the properties that a vector norm should have is that the norm of $c\mathbf v$ is equal to $\lvert c\rvert$ times the norm of $\mathbf v$.

Comment: @amd But the norm of $1+i$ is $2$, according to the field-theoretic definition.

Comment: Which also fails to be absolutely homogeneous.